# AWS Glue Python Shell Job Connect Timeout Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, etl, aws-glue

Trying to run AWS Glue Python Shell Job but gives me Connect Timeout Error

Error Image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHpHg.png

Script      : https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQxkj.png

Comment: There's relevante information in the images. If they go offline context for the question will be lost. Also, it doesn't others searching the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you didn't added secretsmanager endpoint to your VPC. As the traffic will not leave [AWS network](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/vpc-endpoint.html) there will not be internet access inside your Glue job's VPC. So if you want to connect to secretsmanager then you need to add it to your VPC.

Refer to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoint-overview.html) on how you can add this to your VPC and [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/setup-vpc-for-glue-access.html) to make sure you have properly configured security groups.

Comment: Great! Works now. Also, thank you for the explanation Prabhakar!

Comment: @Atul I'm getting the similar error but the endpoint URL is different.
endpoint URL : "https://glue.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/"
What might be the cause? please help